# Conditional day distribution probability

Tags: probability, random-variables

Let $X$ be a random day of the week, coded so that Monday is 1, Tuesday is 2,
etc. (so $X$ takes values 1, 2,..., 7, with equal probabilities). Let $Y$ be the next day after $X$ (again represented as an integer between 1 and 7). Do $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution? What is $P(X < Y )$?

Comment: What are your thoughts?  You receive better response if you show willingness to be part of the solution and not just own the problem.

Comment: Note that $X\lt Y$ except when $X=7$.

Comment: Thanks Andre. @Graham - Sometimes its just that problem is seemingly simple but one just doesnt get an idea why he is not getting it. So no point providing unstructured thoughts. But your point taken in good spirit.

Answer (score 0):

They should have the same distribution

$P(X<Y) = P(X \not= 7) = \dfrac{6}{7}$

Comment: Thanks Rahul. This makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have:
$$\begin{align}
P(X=x) = & \begin{cases} 1/7 & : x\in \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\} \\ 0 & : \text{else}\end{cases}
\\[2ex]
P(Y=y) = & \begin{cases} P(X=y-1) & : y\in\{2,3,4,5,6,7\} \\ P(X=7) & : y=1 \\ 0 & : \text{else}\end{cases}
\\[1ex] = & \begin{cases} 1/7 & : y\in \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\} \\ 0 & : \text{else}\end{cases}\end{align}$$

So now, do these look like the same distribution? (Y/N)

---

Also, notice that $X<Y$ *except* when $X=7$, then $Y=1$, so $P(X<Y) = \ldots$ ?